# Options to print label with barcode?

Tags: delphi, printing, label, barcode

I bought an entry-level Brother label printer, and I need to print this type of label from Delphi:

http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/3557/delphiclothlabel2.jpg

(The barcode was simply created using the [free 3of9 TTY font](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/), although some VCL components are available to create a barcode directly.)

I read that the standard way is to use Rave Reports, but it looks like a pretty big tool and I've never used it before.

Before I go ahead and spend time learning Rave Reports, I'd like to ask experience Delphi developers whether there aren't easier ways to do this. For instace, what about creating some image on-the-fly and send this to the printer?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps some answers here would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919676

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'll experiment, and see if the Printers object is good enough, or I need to use some reporting tool (I read that FastReport is a better option than QuickReports or Rave). Maybe just printing a RichEdit could do :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the barcode available as an image, you can just print it using the Printer object in unit Printers.

```
uses
  Printers;
...
Printer.BeginDoc;
try
  Printer.Canvas.Draw (PosX, PosY, FBarcodeBitmap);
finally
  Printer.EndDoc;
end;
```

If you just want to print the barcode, this might be easier than get yourself used to Rave Reports.

Answer (score 0):

Common barcodes contains CRC, so "barcode font" is not working. You have to use some reporting engine or create barcode by hand using some Barcode Component.

Comment: Code 39 does not have a CRC, but it does have a start and stop character (*) that you must remember to include.

Comment: That said, a true barcode component will provide better results with fewer headaches and is probably worth the money if this is a commercial project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard TRichEdit component. It have the Print method.
Simply:

```
  rich1.Print('title');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly could render your canvas in code and then shove it off to the printer, I think that you will find value in using a reporting tool.  We have used QuickReports for years to generate our barcode labels with great success.

The biggest value that I see of a reporting tool over rendering to a canvas in code is the WYSIWYG aspect of the reporting tool.  You will be able to much of your layout and tweaking on screen at design-time.